# Json.NET DeserializeObject allow constructor exception to bubble up

Tags: c#, exception, json.net, event-bubbling

I am using the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string value)` method to deserialize an object of type `T` from a `string`.

In a custom class (which I am attempting to deserialize) I perform checks on the arguments supplied to the constructor and can throw an `ArgumentNullException`. However, this exception does not bubble up through the deserializer and to the original caller, and therefore the exception stays unhandled inside the constructor.

This is the generic method I am using in a helper class:

```
public static T FromJsonString<T>(string json)
{
    try
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
    catch(ArgumentNullException)
    {
        // Would like to handle exception here, but never reached
    }
}
```

My class constructor example:

```
[JsonConstructor]
public Profile(string name, ...)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) { throw new ArgumentNullException("name"); }
    // ...
}
```

I have attempted using `JsonSerializerSettings` when calling `DeserializeObject<T>()`, for example the `Error` property, however this made no difference.

How can I make the exception bubble up and not stay inside the constructor of my class?

Comment: Why not use a simple guard clause like if (json.isNullOrWhitespace) throw new argumentNullException() ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not VS debug exception setting issue? I've tried something like this and the exception is "bubbling up" as usual.

Comment: @IvanStoev I will check the debug exception settings now

Comment: @PaoloMontgomeryRusso That is not possible as the whole json string may have content, yet the information inside is not compliant with the constructor checks, therefore it must be checked inside the constructor

Comment: @IvanStoev You were right, it was a VS debug setting problem, automatically set to break as it is not handled immediately, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by Visual Studio breaking on the exception as it is classed as "user-unhandled". In Debug > Windows > Exception Settings you can change which exceptions break and which do not.